# Special Effects algorithm, library and books

Tags: image-processing, effects

I am looking at [The Special Effects In Picasa](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/picasa-101-how-to-master-the-special-effects-in-picasa/) article.

Where can I find the following:

1. C/C++ or Java open source library to do it
2. Good books and/or articles to learn the algorithms how to do it myself

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve most of the effects on that page by color manipulation ([white balance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance)) and [spatial filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur).

Before you go down the path of using libraries to achieve this, I recommend playing around with image manipulation software like [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and trying to replicate the effects.  After you're sure you know what you're doing, go ahead and try and code it up.

For libraries, have a look at [opencv](http://www.willowgarage.com/pages/software/opencv).  There are also [Java wrappers](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) for that library if that is your language of choice (Java has its own imaging libraries as well, but I haven't used them).  For books, my personal favorite is [Gonzalez & Woods](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/DIP-3E/dip3e_main_page.htm) -- the first few chapters will get you started.  For articles, [Google](http://www.google.com) is your friend.